# Grep to find a word matching a specific pattern and ignore accents

Tags: grep, locale

This is a homework question that I have only been able to partially solve.

I want to use `grep` to find words in a list that contain three 'e's separated by 't's, and also do an accent insensitive search.

The closest I could get with regular expressions was this:

```
grep 'e.*t.*e.*t.*e' mylist
```

I get two issues with this:

1. I don't understand how to do an accent insensitive search with a pattern like this. I've only heard of equivalence class operators recently and I don't know how to include them in the syntax of my search.
2. The matched patterns I get with this search do not include repeating 't's.

Comment: Does "_accent insensitive_" mean `ü` matches `u`, or that it matches `ue`?

Comment: Edited.
Yes, I'm looking to do a search that ignores accents. Let's say I'm looking for all `e`s, then I should be able to find  `éèêë` as well.

Comment: Looks like you were on the right lines. Would `grep '[eéêèë]'` (etc.) work for you?

Comment: It probably would, but isn't there a regular expression that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your regex engine supports them, you can essentially just replace the character `e` by its equivalence class `[[=e=]]`

Ex.

```
$ grep -m 10 '[[=e=]].*t.*[[=e=]].*t.*[[=e=]]' /usr/share/dict/french
absentéiste
absentéistes
anesthésiste
anesthésistes
cafés-théâtres
café-théâtre
casse-tête
centimètre
centimètres
centripète
```

See [Collating Sequences and Character Equivalents](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#coll)

Comment: Ok that works. This is what I was looking for. For some reasons, I thought the results I had with my initial search ignored cases in which patterns had two `t`s. Might have overlooked it.