# How does pattern matching work in grep for accented characters (eg. á, è, ò)

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ripgrep

What characters match the following regex :

```
^[a-zA-Z]$
```

Specifically, should characters with accents (eg. á, è, ò) match this regex? Or just 26 lower and upper case alphabets?
I have tried to [check this](https://regex101.com/r/KN4fgg/1) in an online regex, and accented characters did not match.

When I tried it out with `grep` on my Linux (Ubuntu) machine it **did match** the accented characters.
While `rg`(ripgrep) **did not match** it.

[image]

I can match accented characters with `rg` using `[A-zÀ-ÿ]`

But is there a way to exclude accented characters from matching in `grep`?

PS: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505477/grep-to-find-a-word-matching-a-specific-pattern-and-ignore-accents) question talks about how accented chars can be included, not excluded.

Comment: Standard text utilities like `grep` use the current locale. If your locale's collation order puts accented characters with the plain letters then they are included. `C` is a standard locale that does NOT collate accented letters together e.g. assuming your data is in UTF-8 (likely nowadays especially if it contains nonASCII) `(echo e; echo é) | LANG=C.UTF-8 grep '[a-z]'`